# Nginx avoid removing double trailing slash in path param when proxy pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have config in my nginx:

```
    location /image-optimizer/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.20:80/;
    }
```

The problem is when nginx proxy passes it removes double trailing slash in path parameter. For example when I call:

http://localhost/image-optimizer/upload/w_500,h_500,q_90/https://m0.cl/t/butterfly-3000.jpg

service on 192.168.1.20:80 receive:
http://192.168.1.20:80/upload/w_500,h_500,q_90/https:/m0.cl/t/butterfly-3000.jpg

Nginx removes double // in https://

How to avoid it?

P.s. Trying with urlencode with no luck.

https%3A%2Fm0.cl%2Ft%2Fbutterfly-3000.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You use this directive

`merge_slashes off;`